# How to make the values of the string array doesn't change?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

In the following piece of my code:

```
 while((grp = getgrent()) != NULL)
        {
                if(belong_to(username,grp->gr_mem) || strcmp(username,grp->gr_name) == 0)
                {
                        ugs[counter] = grp->gr_name;
                        printf("%s",ugs[counter]);
                        counter++;
                        putchar('\n');
                }

        }
```

After the while loop exits, I get the ugs array of strings to be equal to the `grp->gr_name value`which destroys the whole idea am doing that am trying to basically fill up the ugs array based on a condition.

How can I fix that? So I just one the value of the `grp->gr_name` at that if condition moment.

Comment: Each call to `getgrent()` overwrites the previous one's data.  Therefore, you need to make copies of the strings if you don't want the saved values to change.

Comment: Specifically, look here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getgrent.3.html: `The return value may point to a static area, and may be overwritten
       by subsequent calls to getgrent(), getgrgid(3), or getgrnam(3).`

Comment: Please, don't submit pieces of code... read the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page.  It's very important you submit verifiable code, as you can transcript the code and eliminate the errors there.  If you knew where the error is, there should be no necessity of this requirement, but what to ask then? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - here's a complete example that might help with this, and your [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54150384/why-is-getpwent-function-repeating-entries-in-the-etc-passwd-file):

test.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include <pwd.h>

char * list_members(char **members, char *buff);

int main()
{
        int n_grentries = 0, n_pwentries = 0;
        struct group *group;
        struct passwd *passwd;
        char buff[80];

        while((group = getgrent()) != NULL) {
            n_grentries++;
            printf("Group name: %s, ID: %d, members: %s\n",
                group->gr_name, group->gr_gid, list_members(group->gr_mem, buff));
        }
        endgrent();

        while((passwd = getpwent()) != NULL) {
            n_pwentries++;
            printf("User name: %s, UID: %d, shell: %s\n",
                passwd->pw_name, passwd->pw_uid, passwd->pw_shell);
        }
        endpwent();

        printf("There are  %d groups and %d users on the system.\n",
            n_grentries, n_pwentries);
        return 0;
}

char * list_members(char **members, char *buff)
{
    buff[0] = '\0';
    while (members && *members) {
        if (*buff)
          strcat (buff, ", ");
        strcat (buff, *members);
        members++;
    }
    return buff;
}
```

Sample output:

```
Group name: root, ID: 0, members: paulsm, 
Group name: daemon, ID: 1, members: 
Group name: bin, ID: 2, members:
Group name: adm, ID: 4, members: syslog, paulsm, 
...
User name: root, UID: 0, shell: /bin/bash
User name: daemon, UID: 1, shell: /usr/sbin/nologin
User name: bin, UID: 2, shell: /usr/sbin/nologin
User name: sys, UID: 3, shell: /usr/sbin/nologin
...
There are  72 groups and 45 users on the system.
```